# Google ads in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-ads-api

I made a new theme in Wordpress before a year. And now i am updating as per requirement.

I have used Navayan Subscribe in this system. And i get Google ads in that place(frontend) and other place too(middle of the page). I don't know where are they coming from. As i have never used Google ads in clients website.  You can check [this](http://nepalbirds.com/endangered-birds/) page on the right hand side.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that the ads are coming from the widgets.

Go to **Appearance > Widgets** and check there.

If they are not there, check the code inside *sidebar.php* file by going to **Appearance > Editor** and open Sidebar.

You can also disable your plugins to see if some plugin is a cause the ads.

If still no luck then check other php pages for malicius code in the theme by looking for encrypted php code that looks like this:

```
eval(gzinflate(base64_decode('80jNycl...
```

Comment: Google ads were coming from widget in text box. I removed it and its done. :)
Thanks